# How can I replace the contents of all files in a directory with another file?

Tags: file, bash, replace

I'm trying to write a simple bash script that replaces all the files in a directory with a new file, but preserves the name of each file being replaced.

It seems like this should be easy, so my apologies in advance if this is obvious.

Comment: What content do you want in the new files - should they just be empty?

Comment: Replacing each file with what though?  A copy from somewhere else?  New content?  From where?

Answer (score 3):

Since you just want the contents of the new file but keep the file names the same, you can do this in one step with `cat`.

The following two scripts work recursively and with any file name, even ones that contain spaces or newlines or whatever else might break if you tried to parse `ls` output.

#### Bash > 2.x

```
#!/bin/bash
newFile="/path/to/newFile"
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  cat "$newFile" > "$file"
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

#### Bash 4.x

```
#!/bin/bash
newFile="/path/to/newFile"
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
  cat "$newFile" > "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *; do
  if [ -f "${i}" ] ; then 
    cat /dev/null > "${i}";
  fi;
done
```

Comment: don't forget to quote your variables, otherwise this will break with files that have spaces. Also, he wants to replace the contents with another file, I'm going to assume that is not /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for file in *; do
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    > "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: This answer is better than some others as it doesn't fork an external process from the shell to truncate each file.

Comment: @Phil But he doesn't want to truncate the file, he wants to replace the contents with another file

Comment: @Phil hmm, apparently it was. I put it back because there is nothing in his question that hints that he wants the files to be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel installed:

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 cat /path/to/foo \> {}
```

If you are in a dir that only contains files (no dirs) then this is shorter and maybe easier to remember:

```
parallel cat /path/to/foo \> {} ::: *
```

It deals correctly with files containing space, ' and " (for filenames containing newline, you need the above).

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: http://pi.dk/1

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read name; do
 cp "/directory/$name" /backup/
 mv /new/replacement "/directory/$name"
 echo "replaced /directory/$name with /new/replacement and stored backup in /backup"
done <<< "$(ls -1 /directory/)"
```

you will likely plan to change /directory /backup and /new/replacement in the code example.
You can use "find" instead of "ls" to do it recursive.
It won't have problems with spaces now.

Comment: This breaks for filenames that have spaces. Why not just us a glob rather than call `ls` in a subshell?

Comment: Please don't edit other people's answers to add your own notes. That is what comments are for. And please don't sign your edits; we can already see who edited a post.

Comment: Sorry, I have to give this -1 due to the fact that you are parsing `ls` instead of just using globs. Please read [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) why parsing `ls` should be avoided at all costs

Comment: In any normal real world directory this will work fine and can easily extended with "find" for recursive replacements. You are right that globs could be used but the "never use ls" article creates a highly artificial problem.
I've added quotation so "spa ces" are not an issue.

Instead of downvoting the only real answer you should correct your example. You only read the question TOPIC instead of reading the full question. He does not want to "zero size all files" he wants to "replace all files"

Comment: @John 1) You didn't fix your script by adding quotes around the variable names. The problem is that the shell performs word splitting on the output of `ls`. It still breaks horribly with file names with spaces. I've seen plenty of "real world directories" that contain files with spaces in their names.  Why use an inferior external tool when the shell already provides globbing nativity that doesn't suffer from this problem? 2) Perhaps you confused my answer with somebody else, but I too do not "zero size all file" but rather "replace all files"

Comment: You mean `for file in /directory/*` ... See http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls

Comment: @Siege: That was an edit in progress ^^
I've modified it to treat spaces and most other "special chars" in a filename correctly now.

Comment: @John Ok. So now that you used a here-string, you are forking bash off to call `ls` for no additional functionality that globbing gives you, why? Beyond that, your script is still broken in two more places. 1) you don't check to see if "$name" is a file or directory 2) after your first `mv` command, the `replacement` file is no longer in the `/new` directory for subsequent iterations.

Comment: and where is @user1120422 while all of this is going on? Good luck and peace to all ;-)